# Ubuntu autoinstall late-commands issue with special chars

Tags: server, iso, subiquity

I need to run few commands after installation is complete. But installer is failing when I use this command:

```
curl -X POST -k -H "Content-Type: plain/text, Accept: plain/text" -d <somedata> <URL>
```

When I get into console of installer I find this: ""Failed loading yaml blob ...mapping values are not allowed". The problem it found is at colon (:) char in "Accept: plain/text".

I tried escaping with \ for colon (:) but that didnt help.

Any help here is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution! It was a simple YAML validation error. I should have run YAML validation before posting this question.

Changing the command to the following fixed the issue:

```
curl -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type:plain/text, Accept:plain/text' -d <some text data> <some url>
```